# Input a textbox value from c# into a html file?

Tags: c#

I am trying to input the c# TextBox value be displayed in a Html file. How can you input a Textbox value from c# and have the value display in a html file?

Comment: Please review [ask]

Answer (score -2):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //put textbox value in html file C:\Users\files\source\repos\MyApplication\MyApplication\bin\Debug
        String Header = ReadHtmlFile("file.html");
        //sb.AppendLine(Header);
        sb.Append(Header.Replace("[[NA]]", textBox1.Text));
        return sb.ToString();
```